# Is this participle clause sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, participial-phrases, absolute-constructions

How do you think about this sentence? Is it ok grammatically?

- Having been in shape, I go to gym twice a week.

`

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in many
common and less exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners
don’t realize that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this,
that, these, those* which native speakers customarily use in these cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically it's fine, except that *gym* is not one of those institutions (like *school* and *church*) that doesn't need an article. So *I go to **the** gym twice a week*.

As regards meaning: it doesn't make sense. *Having been* is nearly always not just prior, but a cause or reason.

What you have written means approximately "Because I was already in shape, I go to the gym twice a week". If that's what you meant, then you said it. But it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: So helpful, thank you very much.

Comment: If I want to say "because I'm care about my shape therefore I go to the gym twice a week" with that grammar, how can I say it?

Comment: "having had be in shape, I go..." is it correct?

Comment: Hello, @keyvansalimi: no, That's not grammatical, but it still seems to be saying that you were already in shape. What you probably want, if you insist on using a participle, is _Caring about my shape, I go to the gym twice a week_. But that is a bit literary. Most people would say, as you (nearly) did: _Because I care about my shape, I go to the gym twice a week_.

Comment: Hello @ColinFine: thank you very much, I've learned a lot from you. 

Comment: I make a sentence which I think is better, "Having taken my shape into consideration, I never miss out on workout", is it ok?